# How can you create a "sticky footer" in inDesign?

Tags: website-design, adobe-indesign

Sticky footers in web development are basically footers that will always either stick to the bottom if the content isn't tall enough to vertically fill the browser or they stick after the bottom of the content after scrolling.  I don't much need the first one, but I'd like the ability to have a footer on my master page always end up at the bottom of the content.  I'm coding a website responsively using alternate and liquid layouts.

Is this possible in InDesign?

[Sticky Footers Reference](http://www.cssstickyfooter.com/)

Comment: ... what are you trying to create because the main use of InDesign is for Print and I'm not sure how the concept of a static footer would work in a printed document?

Comment: Are you trying to build an ePub or publish to a site from InDesign?

Comment: The primary purpose is for web, I felt that was somewhat implied in the link I posted, but I'll edit my post to be more clear.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look into `anchored objects`: you can anchor a frame inside another frame and set some of the parameters (e.g. "y offset relative to bottom edge of parent object"). Play around with it a little to before you commit to a large document: it might get "hairy" depending on complexity.

Comment: As I understand anchored objects imply having text don't they?  Can I anchor one frame to another without necessarily having text or content in either one of them?

Comment: to be honest I have only ever inserted a graphic frame into a text box so that it stays with the text. Worth trying. I have found that in many cases, it is better to be as "manual as possible" unless there is a good reason. Many times, automation is an impediment to flexibility for fixed layouts.

Comment: That's good enough of an explanation for me.  You win.